# How to pass the ID in URL to next page

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a Page where I am displaying records along with ADD buttons. When I click on ADD button I am navigating user to another page to add new records.

I have used the ActionLink to navigate to next page. But I need to pass the ID also in my actionlink. My Problem comes here is how to get the ID and pass in actionlink.

Here is my code :

View :

```
@model IEnumerable<MyProject.Models.Record>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
   <div>
      @Html.ActionLink("ADD", "AddRecords", new { id = 8765})
  </div>
}
```

Comment: Get the ID from where? We have no idea what your model is or what property contains the ID

Comment: Your code should do what you want. Is it not working?

Answer (score 0):

Just need an action inside ADD controller

```
public class ADDController

{

public ActionResult AddRecords(int id)
{
  //do something  with id
}

}
```